# Angular 4 : Best practise in angular if page have multiple tabs

Tags: angular

I've a page which has multiple tabs. It's huge form divided into tabs. So, how to divide multiple tabs in a page to different components and import all of them in single component along with its functionalities. Should all the tab be treated as parent and import in one single child or there should be one parent and all the tabs should be children? Each tab is different but belongs to same resource or belongs to one huge form. Part of this form is not going to be used elsewhere. I am just trying to divide one huge form or problem into sections. If possible also provide folder structure.

Here is the folder structure that I've tried :

```
(Folder)
residence-|
          |-(Folder)add-form-|
          |                  |-(Tab 1)basic-info-|
          |                  |                   |-component.ts
          |                  |                   |-component.html
          |                  |                   |-component.specs
          |                  |                   |-component.css
          |                  |-(Tab 2)details-|
          |                  |                |-component.ts
          |                  |                |-component.html
          |                  |                |-component.specs
          |                  |                |-component.css
          |                  |-(Tab 3)other-|
          |                  |              |-component.ts
          |                  |              |-component.html
          |                  |              |-component.specs
          |                  |              |-component.css
          |
          |-edit-form -|
          |            |-(Tab 1)basic-info-|
          |            |                   |-component.ts
          |            |                   |-component.html
          |            |                   |-component.specs
          |            |                   |-component.css
          |            |-(Tab 2)details-|
          |            |                |-component.ts
          |            |                |-component.html
          |            |                |-component.specs
          |            |                |-component.css
          |            |-(Tab 3)other-|
          |            |              |-component.ts
          |            |              |-component.html
          |            |              |-component.specs
          |            |              |-component.css
```

Comment: You’re getting way too caught up in folder structure. There isn’t a clear or correct answer to this question. You probably don’t want one giant form as that will be difficult to manage. Ask yourself why is it divided into tabs? Is each tab a different but related resource? Will parts of this form need to be used elsewhere? Am I doing things in a reusable manner? Answering these questions will help you structure your project and maybe help you improve your apps ui/Ux

Comment: @bryan60 what I wanted is to simplify/divide the problem. I just wanted to know the best practice to do this.

Comment: There is no answer to this question. It is far too app specific. Just make a decision. Chances are you’ll regret it later but you’ll learn something.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would personally make use of the Redux architecture.
It basically acts as a "database" for your frontend.

You may take a look at an library called `ngrx`.

Here are some tutorials I would look into:

- https://youtu.be/9P5DTlg9oLc
- https://youtu.be/N_UQx8dPPkc
- https://youtu.be/kPkTXdToYV0